# Nested arrays - Why my for loop does not follow the standard procedure flow?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I would be grateful if someone could explain me this bug.

I started to learn programming and came across this task:

Your task, is to create NxN multiplication table, of size provided in parameter. For example, when given size is 3, the returned value should be [[1,2,3],[2,4,6],[3,6,9]].

I came up with this solution.

```js
const multiplicationTable = (size) => {
  
  // creating the correct size of the multiplication table
  let array = [];
  array.length = size;
  let array2 = [];
  array2.length = size;
  
  for (let m = 0; m < size; m++) {
    array[m] = array2;
  }
  // assigning correct numbers
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    let base = i + 1;
    for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      let factor = j + 1;
      array[i][j] = factor * base;
    }
  }

  return array;
}
```

I know, that there might be more suitable solution, but I would like to ask, why this particular one does not work.

The problem seems to be with the variable "base". My intent was to set the value to 1, then hold it throughout the following nested loop, afterwards increase it by one and hold it again throughout iteration of another nested for loop.

The problem is that when I run the code, it does not hold the number 1, but it already sets itself to the last number. So my result when calling the function with a number 3 equals --> [ [ 3, 6, 9 ], [ 3, 6, 9 ], [ 3, 6, 9 ] ].

Thank you for any explanation, because for now, I cannot get my head around it. :)

Comment: The problem is that all locations in array refer to the same array2.

Comment: https://javascript.info/object-copy - as an additional note, `array.length = size;` is unnecessary in javascript, if you set the values later anyways.

Comment: That was the problem that you referenced the same array2. If you go with this line of code `array[m] = [];` inside the first `for` loop, that will create a new array for each "line" in the matrix, and the result will be correct :)

Comment: I am sorry for a delayed answer, but thank you very much for your help. I understand the mistake I had done. :)